# SQL: connection.close - Need some hints for a excerice

Tags: java, sql

I became a hint to put in the code a finally statement with a 'connection.close' before the first catch statement appears. I don't see any ways to implement that, could you please give me a short hint how I could handle that?! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint is just a hint.  You should close connections you created.  However, you didn't create it in this method and you might want to use it again later so I suspect it would be a bad idea to close it here.